# SOLIDWORKS-Bolting a COTS part from a STEP File onto an Assembly

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks, bolting

## Problem

I have a STEP file with a few holes for bolts. I'm hoping to bolt this part into stock material in Solidworks.

## Example

My first thought is to extend the holes into other connected components in an assembly to ensure both parts now have the same hole profile.

I imported a STEP file into this basic assembly.
[image: The assembly has one internal part and one STEP file.]

Then I mated the part to the assembly so it can't move.
[image]

Then I drew onto the face on the assembly that needed to be cut.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Then I exited the sketch, and Solidworks took me to the "Extruded cut" dialog.
[image]

Now holes are cut through the material.
[image]

Finally, I find and import the STEP models of the bolts they provided to my assembly. Each one is manually mated.
[image]

**There has to be a more standard/convenient way to bolt in COTS parts, I'd hope?**

Comment: Note: This question was moved from the Robotics Stack Exchange: 

https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23608/solidworks-bolting-a-cots-part-from-a-step-file-onto-an-assembly

Comment: Well, the only easier way is to model the holes first in original part. But i mean how many minutes does this take?  How many minutes do you expect to save.

Comment: The strength of SolidWorks is being able to adjust design in assembly.  When I first started with SW, I stressed over each part being perfect before assembly.  Now, the assembly is a key component in the design phase.  There are macros, which may help, but you have to invest time in learning/developing the macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other way to do this that I know of is to draw circles and extruded cut as usual to make the holes, then edit the circles in the assembly and create an external reference between your drawing and the holes in the STEP part.